# Separated arabic font using html color tag in webview and text view

Tags: android, html, webview, textview, arabic

Hi and thanks for your help:
I want to make text like this:

[image]

so used textview and:

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"red\">"+
                "ال"+"</font>"+
                "<font color=\"black\">"+
                "سلام علیکم"+"</font>";));
```

every thing is OK in android 4.4.2 and up. but in android 4.2.2 it is:

[image]

so what i must do?
is there a component, library or solution?
PS:
1-one week searching and no result :(
2-using webview and span tags: all versions has this problem :(
3-I test many font faces and problem remains :(
4-in all browsers like Firefox and IE the text display is OK! is this just android problem?

Answer (score 1):

Append [zero-width joiners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner) at the end of "ال" and at the beginning of "سلام علیکم". Example: "ال‍" and "‍سلام علیکم".

You might want to write either [the Unicode character itself](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200d/browsertest.htm) into the source code or the HTML entity `&zwj;`

Answer (score 0):

Use sp (scaled pixels) has scalable ratio: sp = px * ratio * scale. Where ratio never changes, but scale is user configurable. This scale can be used by people who need larger font sizes, for example, to use device more comfortably.
May be you get some idea.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/index.html

Comment: thanks. but I don't understand how to resolve my problem with sp = px * ratio * scale because it is in text and android version problem and not aspect ratio.